How to make `std::from_range` move the elements when it makes sense?
Consider this code:
#include <ranges>
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    template <typename U>
    A(U &&input) : v(std::from_range, std::forward<U>(input)) {}
};

int main()
{
    A<std::unique_ptr<int>> a(std::list<std::unique_ptr<int>>{});
}

It doesn't compile, as std::from_range tries to copy the elements instead of moving them. run on gcc.godbolt.org
What is the correct and idiomatic solution here? I want it to automatically move the elements if source range is an rvalue and owns the elements.

I know std::views::as_rvalue exists, but deciding when to apply it requires a lengthy condition:

The input range must be an rvalue, and
It must own the elements (std::borrowed_range<U &> == false, perhaps? not sure)

Sure, I can write out this condition manually, but naively hoped that Ranges has a built-in solution to this problem.

"Sure, I can write out this condition manually" I don't think there is an exact correct condition because when you pass in a rvalue view this also moves its underlying element which is not right.

@康桓瑋 That's why I also suggest checking std::borrowed_range == false. But I'm no longer sure this is enough...

I believe this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77877816/11638718

@康桓瑋 Aha, so the answer is "it's impossible to construct a proper condition for this".

Judging by Is there a move-or-copy equivalent of std::forward for perfect forwarding in std::ranges?, not only there's no built-in solution, but also std::borrowed_range<U> == false is not the valid condition to check if it's safe to move the element.
So we need some other heuristic to check if it's safe to move the element, perhaps something like this:
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
concept IsOwningContainer = requires(std::remove_cvref_t<T> &t)
{
    t.erase(t.begin());
};

template <typename T>
struct A
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    template <typename U>
    A(U &&source) : v(std::from_range, source) {}

    template <typename U>
    requires (!std::is_reference_v<U>) && IsOwningContainer<U>
    A(U &&source) : v(std::from_range, source | std::views::as_rvalue) {}
};

